# Airflow not scheduling correctly

Tags: python-3.x, etl, airflow

I have set my task to be ran daily, yet the program is ran one day behind, I was wondering if there was an answer to this?

```
 default_args ={
  'owner': 'airflow',
  'start_date' : datetime(year=2016,month=10,day=8),
  'depends_on_past': True,
  'email_on_failure': False,
  'email_on_retry': True,
  'retries:': 3,
  'retry_delay' :timedelta(minutes=2)}
```

I am on PST, so even if the scheduler is on UTC, it should not affect why it is off by 2 days, since UTC is faster. And by a day. As in, as of Oct 18 6:00PM PST, the last run of the scheduled task is Oct 17, not on Oct 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow schedules dags for the previous schedule interval.

A dag with the cron schedule `@daily` will hence receive the `execution_date` (passed into the executed task's context) of `2016/10/14 00:00:00` when run on `2016/10/15 00:00:00`.
The idea is that if a dag is running at `2016/10/15 00:00:00` it is probably running some job over the period 2016/10/14 00:00:00 to 2016/10/15 00:00:00.